# Charging 7th generation iPad using MacBook Pro 61W USB-C Power adapter

Tags: ipad, battery, charging

When I'm not at home, I'm used to charge both my MacBook Pro (2017) and my iPhone 8 with the MacBook charger for convenience. I have recently bought a 7th generation iPad, and I would like to know if I can charge this device too with the MacBook Pro power adapter, without damaging its battery.

From what I know, the iPhone 8 supports Fast Charging, while the iPad does not, but can it be charged anyway with this MacBook Pro power adapter?

Charger output: 20.3V, 3A or 9V, 3A or 5.2V 2.4A.

Comment: Your iPad has a Lightning port, not USB-C. So you'll to get from USB C on the power adaptor to a Lightning plug.

Comment: You are correct. Like the iPhone 8, also the iPad has a Lightning connector. I would certainly use a USB-C to Lightning cable to connect the iPad to the power adapter. My question was: would this harm the iPad battery?

Comment: The iPad comes with a 12W charger, so 5.2V at 2.4A should be  fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if I can charge this device too with the MacBook Pro power adapter, without damaging its battery.

Yes. It would be safe to use your MacBook Pro 61W power adapter to charge your iPad.

It is your device that actually determines the power it receives, not the charger.

However, the Apple Support document on Fast charging doesn't mention 7th generation iPad. So while it is possible to charge your iPad, you may not be able to fast charge it.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208137